# Is there a version of rubyzip gem for jruby?

Tags: jruby

Is there a version of rubyzip gem of jruby? Or something similar to rubyzip but it does not require native extension.

Answer (score 0):

I found it: there is "rubyzip" gem which works well with jruby.